# Find digits (below certian number) on the page from specific work until specific last word is found

Tags: regex

Would like some support here with a Regex.

**Regular expression**:

```
(\scaptain\s.*b([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s[0-4][0-9][0-9]\s.*morgan\s)
```

**Test string:**

```
bla bla bla captain bla bla 1 250 2 450 9 501 11 900 21 900 30 400 31 1023 morgan bla bla bla
```

**Question:** Match a 3 digit number below 500 after the word "captain"and until the word "morgan" appears.
Goal: Match the 3 digit number below 500
All support much appreciated!

Comment: Tell your teacher, that regex is not matching number in a range. He should know that.

Comment: ...but you might use: `/(?<=captain.*)\b[1-4]\d{2}\b(?=.*morgan)/g`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with positive and negative lookahead:

`\b[0-4][0-9][0-9]\b(?=.*morgan)(?!.*captain)`

- `\b` word break
- `[0-4][0-9][0-9]` and number from 000 to 499
- `(?=.*morgan)`has to be followed by morgan somewhere
- `(?!.*captain)` can not be followed by captain anywhere

if you don't want to have 000 to 099 included then it would be
`\b[1-4][0-9][0-9]\b(?=.*morgan)(?!.*captain)`

What is not covered is, that the string has to contain `captain`.

example: https://regex101.com/r/uFtBiy/1

Comment: Thanks Lutz for your answer. Working! I will now try and teach myself :-)

Comment: depending on the language you are (e.g. JS) using Poul Baks version will work better, as it requires a `captain` before. But some flavours of RE  (like e.g. python)  don't permit variable length look behind.